# Vue Select component get value id of selected array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i used Vue Select component and i'm working all day trying to get **value id** from selected array

```
<v-select multiple label="name" :on-change="consoleCallback" :options="option" :value.sync="option.id" :value="id" v-model="users_id">
</v-select>


import vSelect from 'vue-select'
export default {
        components: {vSelect},
        props: ['title'],
        data(){
            return{
                model: {
                    'title':'',
                },
                users_id:[],
                option: [],
methods: {
            fetchData(id){
                let vm = this;
                let dataInput = vm.model;
                axios.get('/subject/' +id+ '/edit',dataInput)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
                        Vue.set(vm.$data, 'option', response.data.option)
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cVyw.jpg)

Comment: I think it is `on-change="consoleCallback"` not `:on-change="consoleCallback" `, there is no **colon(:)**

Comment: I'd try 'v-on:change' or '@change' for short

Comment: on-change="consoleCallback" not :on-change="consoleCallback" , there is no colon(:) it hang up

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/) for Vue Select you should use on-change and not :on-change. The On-Change Callback example in the documentation looks like this:

```
<v-select on-change="consoleCallback" :options="countries"></v-select>
```

and

```
methods: {
  consoleCallback(val) {
    console.dir(JSON.stringify(val))
  },

  alertCallback(val) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(val))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
              →
this.model = response.data.model

Answer (score 0):

i know its late, but for any one looking for the answer i found this thread on github [here](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/pull/423) where the problem has been solved. the component has an "index" prop which you could set to "id" to get just the id value.

```html
<v-select index="id" multiple label="name" :on-change="consoleCallback" :options="option" :value.sync="option.id" :value="id" v-model="users_id">
</v-select>
```

Comment: As of 3.0 the "index" prop has been replaced with "reduce".

https://vue-select.org/guide/upgrading.html#index-prop-replaced-with-reduce